# What is the VS2022 eqivalent to "Azure Identity Plugin for Visual Studio Code Authentication"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, authentication, visual-studio-2022

im trying to authenticate towards Azure using my local user in VisualStudio2022 in my local development environment using the following:

```
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
```

but nothing is found, and I'm signed in in VS2022.

1. Should credentials be found automatically, or do i need to spesify that it is the VS2022 credentials i want to use?
2. Does https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/identity/identity-vscode/README.md work only for VS-Code, and not vs2022?

**Edit 1:** **Elaboration**: As i understand it, "credentials" can be from "EnvironmentCredentials", "DefaultManagedIdentityCredentials", "AzureCLI" or "AzurePowerSHell".
Beeing logged into azure with corret subscription in VS2022, i expected my credentials to be in one of these to contain my credentials.

Btw: i get a *"DefaultAzureCredential => failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. To troubleshoot, visit"*
What is the "included credentials" ?

**Edit 2**: I can get a token using Azure CLI as descibed here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/identity/identity/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#verify-the-azure-cli-can-obtain-tokens

Comment: are you trying to make a vs extension?

Comment: im trying to autenticate towards azure in my nodejs app - using VS2022, not VScode.

Comment: This appears to be relevant: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/23331

Comment: Man, after reading that, i realized that i wasnt actually getting the secret... so by adding:         const secret = await client.getSecret(secretName);
it worked like a charm (I Misread the error message to be a actual error and not a default statmenet from source, as one of the posts points out.....). So thanks !

Comment: @otk For completeness, can you please post a self answer to this question so it can be closed / for future reference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved using the azure sdk require("@azure/identity");

And i guess its fetching credentials though AzureCLI , event though its not visible when instantiating the credentials, which i was expecting. But its all undefined as can be seen in picture below.

[image]

Then, just trying to get the secret from keyVault it worked, although i'm not 100% sure how its working.

```
const client = new SecretClient(url, credential);
await client.getSecret(secretName);
```